# Linux detect when file has been created, edited or deleted live

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

Good day,
I am not sure where to post the question , I hope this spot will satisfy.

I am wanting to have the ability to know when Linux creates, edits or deletes a file. Ultimately, I was thinking that I would need to write a driver to interface with the kernel and hook the systemcalls.

However, I am thinking that perhaps there is an kernel api for this kind of thing that I could simple attach to.

Maybe even having the disk report file changes might be easier...

Is there a way to do this now and what are some problems with how I want to do this now?

Comment: You might be looking for [`inotify(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

Comment: [whenever.sh](https://gist.github.com/mpapi/4656389) could be helpful. And maybe [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/956311/continuously-detect-new-files-with-inotify-tools-within-multiple-directories-r) also.

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks.